# MySQL escape line breaks exporting into CSV?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a problem I have a "text" field with a bunch of "stories" that are pasted from word and such and as such include things like line breaks and tabs. I want to export to CSV maintaining these or be able to get them back.

But I can't figure out how to escape them so it works? When I export CSV I get a CSV with a bunch of single sentences on multiple rows/columns.

I tried replacing the news lines with other stuff but I kept messing up. Is there an easy way to do this without destroying data?

Comment: Yep, that's how CSV works. You can probaably escape the line breaks to `<br/>` elements.

Comment: ARe you using PHP's fgetcsv() function? Ot are you using MySQL's LOAD DATA command?

Comment: I am using MYSQL export CSV function. Would PHP FGETCSV work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV is not a good format for arbitrary text, but you can *try*

```sql
SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/text.csv'
   FIELDS ESCAPED BY '""' TERMINATED BY ','  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Raises `Field separator argument is not what is expected` Error. Has to be

`ESCAPED BY '"'`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$line.=preg_replace("/\n\t/", ";", preg_replace("/,/", ";", $f['field5'])).',';
```

or

```
$line.=preg_replace("/\n/", ";", preg_replace("/,/", ";", $f['field5'])).',';
```

and in the end you have to display `$line` including header first.

`$f['field5']` - data from db.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `SELECT` with a search and replace kind of thing, where you search for line breaks of `'\n'` and replace them with nothing `''`. A `SELECT` won't actually replace anything in the table itself unless you did an `UPDATE`. See below query example.

```sql
(SELECT 'columnA', 'columnB', 'columnC')
UNION
(SELECT `columnA`, REPLACE(`columnB`, '\n', ''), `columnC`
FROM `yourtable`
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/text.csv'
FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n');
```